# Multiple Image Upload in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My form will have two file input fields and other fields.The user will be sleecting two different types of files and putting in some data. On submit button I want to send both the files along with the accompanying data to the server.

I have come across two Angular File Uploaders

1. [Angular-file-upload (nervgh)](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)
2. [Angular File upload (danial farid)](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

Both allow multiple files but for each file there is one Http request .But the behaviour I want is 1 Post request that sends two files and some JSON data.

My backend is in NodeJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want something like this.

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/fogbugz/bug/create',
        data: { request: $scope.request, files: $scope.files },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: function(data) {
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("request", angular.toJson(data.request));
          for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("File" + (i + 1), data.files[i]);
          }
          formData.append("nFileCount", data.files.length);
          return formData;
        }
      }).success(function(data) {

      }).error(function(error, response) {

      });
```

The important part is that you have to set set Content-Type in your header to undefined instead of multipart/form-data because undefined will set the correct boundary for the form data.